# SVG shapes in css animation all have the same center of rotation

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, sass, css-animations

In the code below I'm trying to make each ellipse rotate a little bit, but it looks like they all have the same center of rotation in the top left corner, so the ones in the top left rotate a lot less than the ones in the bottom right.

How can I give each one it's own center of rotation, so that they would all be moving the same amount(for example, each ellipse would have a center of rotation in it's middle in the middle of the circle)

You can run the code on [this stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-547kdv?file=src%2Fsvg%2FCircles.js)

[image]

```js
import React from 'react';

export default function ellipses() {
  return (
    <div>
      <svg
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        viewBox="0 0 9695 7979"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        style={{
          fillRule: 'evenodd',
          clipRule: 'evenodd',
          strokeLinejoin: 'round',
          strokeMiterlimit: 2
        }}
        className="ellipses"
      >
        <ellipse
          cx="2035.48"
          cy="1591.96"
          rx="326.722"
          ry="426.722"
          style={{ fill: 'rgb(255,180,143)', fillOpacity: 0.73 }}
        />
        <ellipse
          cx="9122.09"
          cy="5698.2"
          rx="326.722"
          ry="426.722"
          style={{ fill: 'rgb(245,230,204)', fillOpacity: 0.73 }}
        />
        <ellipse
          cx="7885.77"
          cy="2720.56"
          rx="326.722"
          ry="26.722"
          style={{ fill: 'rgb(23,233,224)', fillOpacity: 0.73 }}
        />
        <ellipse
          cx="3451.01"
          cy="3586.41"
          rx="326.722"
          ry="426.722"
          style={{ fill: 'rgb(166,74,201)', fillOpacity: 0.73 }}
        />
        <ellipse
          cx="5523.57"
          cy="6024.93"
          rx="326.722"
          ry="426.722"
          style={{ fill: 'rgb(252,205,4)', fillOpacity: 0.73 }}
        />
        <ellipse
          cx="4235.73"
          cy="554.768"
          rx="326.722"
          ry="426.722"
          style={{ fill: 'rgb(255,180,143)', fillOpacity: 0.73 }}
        />
        <ellipse
          cx="3369.51"
          cy="2067.12"
          rx="326.722"
          ry="426.722"
          style={{ fill: 'rgb(23,233,224)', fillOpacity: 0.73 }}
        />
        <ellipse
          cx="7293.46"
          cy="5235.4"
          rx="326.722"
          ry="426.722"
          style={{ fill: 'rgb(166,74,201)', fillOpacity: 0.73 }}
        />
        <ellipse
          cx="443.413"
          cy="3728.84"
          rx="326.722"
          ry="426.722"
          style={{ fill: 'rgb(252,205,4)', fillOpacity: 0.73 }}
        />
        <ellipse
          cx="9448.81"
          cy="647.07"
          rx="245.22"
          ry="345.22"
          style={{ fill: 'rgb(255,180,143)', fillOpacity: 0.73 }}
        />
        <ellipse
          cx="7865.4"
          cy="391.28"
          rx="245.22"
          ry="345.22"
          style={{ fill: 'rgb(245,230,204)', fillOpacity: 0.73 }}
        />
        <ellipse
          cx="6113.37"
          cy="245.22"
          rx="245.22"
          ry="345.22"
          style={{ fill: 'rgb(23,233,224)', fillOpacity: 0.73 }}
        />
        <ellipse
          cx="8550.15"
          cy="1231.54"
          rx="245.22"
          ry="345.22"
          style={{ fill: 'rgb(166,74,201)', fillOpacity: 0.73 }}
        />
        <ellipse
          cx="8976.37"
          cy="4426.6"
          rx="245.22"
          ry="345.22"
          style={{ fill: 'rgb(252,205,4)', fillOpacity: 0.73 }}
        />
        <ellipse
          cx="1538.58"
          cy="4886.94"
          r="426.722"
          style={{ fill: 'rgb(23,233,224)', fillOpacity: 0.73 }}
        />
        <ellipse
          cx="946.273"
          cy="7401.78"
          rx="326.722"
          ry="426.722"
          style={{ fill: 'rgb(166,74,201)', fillOpacity: 0.73 }}
        />
        <ellipse
          cx="2629.18"
          cy="6592.97"
          rx="245.22"
          ry="345.22"
          style={{ fill: 'rgb(252,205,4)', fillOpacity: 0.73 }}
        />
        <ellipse
          cx="465.52"
          cy="5005.88"
          rx="245.22"
          ry="345.22"
          style={{ fill: 'rgb(255,180,143)', fillOpacity: 0.73 }}
        />
        <ellipse
          cx="6600.71"
          cy="3476.06"
          rx="245.22"
          ry="345.22"
          style={{ fill: 'rgb(245,230,204)', fillOpacity: 0.73 }}
        />
        <ellipse
          cx="2879.07"
          cy="7733.67"
          rx="245.22"
          ry="345.22"
          style={{ fill: 'rgb(23,233,224)', fillOpacity: 0.73 }}
        />
        <ellipse
          cx="1115.1"
          cy="387.908"
          rx="326.722"
          ry="426.722"
          style={{ fill: 'rgb(255,180,143)', fillOpacity: 0.73 }}
        />
        <ellipse
          cx="733.143"
          cy="2393.84"
          rx="326.722"
          ry="426.722"
          style={{ fill: 'rgb(166,74,201)', fillOpacity: 0.73 }}
        />
        <ellipse
          cx="245.22"
          cy="6624.27"
          rx="245.22"
          ry="345.22"
          style={{ fill: 'rgb(23,233,224)', fillOpacity: 0.73 }}
        />
        <ellipse
          cx="6113.37"
          cy="1694.15"
          rx="245.22"
          ry="345.22"
          style={{ fill: 'rgb(166,74,201)', fillOpacity: 0.73 }}
        />
        <ellipse
          cx="3369.51"
          cy="5480.62"
          rx="245.22"
          ry="345.22"
          style={{ fill: 'rgb(252,205,4)', fillOpacity: 0.73 }}
        />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
@mixin Circle($num) {
  -webkit-animation: balloon#{$num} 3s ease-in-out infinite;
  -moz-animation: balloon#{$num} 3s ease-in-out infinite;
  -o-animation: balloon#{$num} 3s ease-in-out infinite;
  animation: balloon#{$num} 3s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@mixin gelatine {
  animation: gelatine 10s infinite;
}

.ellipses > ellipse:nth-child(1) {
  @include Circle(2);
  // @include Circle(1);
}
.ellipses > ellipse:nth-child(2) {
  // @include Circle(1);
  @include Circle(2);
  // animation-delay: 1s;
}
.ellipses > ellipse:nth-child(3) {
  // @include Circle(1);
  @include Circle(2);
  // animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.ellipses > ellipse:nth-child(4) {
  // @include Circle(1);
  @include Circle(2);
  // animation-delay: 2s;
}
.ellipses > ellipse:nth-child(5) {
  @include Circle(2);
  // animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
.ellipses > ellipse:nth-child(6) {
  @include Circle(2);
  // @include Circle(1);
  // animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
.ellipses > ellipse:nth-child(7) {
  @include Circle(2);
  // animation-delay: 3s;
}
.ellipses > ellipse:nth-child(8) {
  @include Circle(2);
  // animation-delay: 3.5s;
}
.ellipses > ellipse:nth-child(9) {
  @include Circle(2);
  // animation-delay: 4s;
}
.ellipses > ellipse:nth-child(10) {
  @include Circle(2);
  // animation-delay: 4.5s;
}
.ellipses > ellipse:nth-child(11) {
  @include Circle(2);
  // animation-delay: 5s;
}
.ellipses > ellipse:nth-child(12) {
  @include Circle(2);
  // animation-delay: 5.5s;
}
.ellipses > ellipse:nth-child(13) {
  @include Circle(2);
  // animation-delay: 6s;
}
.ellipses > ellipse:nth-child(14) {
  @include Circle(2);
  // animation-delay: 6.5s;
}
.ellipses > ellipse:nth-child(15) {
  @include Circle(2);
  // animation-delay: 7s;
}
.ellipses > ellipse:nth-child(16) {
  @include Circle(2);
  // animation-delay: 7.5s;
}
.ellipses > ellipse:nth-child(17) {
  @include Circle(2);
  // animation-delay: 8s;
}
.ellipses > ellipse:nth-child(18) {
  @include Circle(2);
  // animation-delay: 9s;
}
.ellipses > ellipse:nth-child(19) {
  @include Circle(2);
  // animation-delay: 9.6s;
}
.ellipses > ellipse:nth-child(20) {
  @include Circle(2);
  // animation-delay: 3.8s;
}
.ellipses > ellipse:nth-child(21) {
  @include Circle(2);
  // animation-delay: 8.3s;
}
.ellipses > ellipse:nth-child(22) {
  @include Circle(2);
  // animation-delay: 2.8s;
}
.ellipses > ellipse:nth-child(23) {
  @include Circle(2);
  // animation-delay: 7.3s;
}
.ellipses > ellipse:nth-child(24) {
  @include Circle(2);
  // animation-delay: 6.2s;
}

.ellipses > ellipse:nth-child(25) {
  @include Circle(2);
  // animation-delay: 6.2s;
}

/* BAllOON 2 5*/
@-webkit-keyframes balloon2 {
  0%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0) rotate(6eg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px) rotate(-4deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes balloon2 {
  0%,
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0) rotate(6deg);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-5px) rotate(-4deg);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes balloon2 {
  0%,
  100% {
    -o-transform: translateY(0) rotate(6deg);
  }
  50% {
    -o-transform: translateY(-5px) rotate(-4deg);
  }
}
@keyframes balloon2 {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(6deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-5px) rotate(-4deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `transform-box: fill-box;`can solve your problem. SVG elements do indeed, by default, have the center around `0,0`. There's a pretty good explainer on the docs page as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box

Comment: You don't set a transform-origin for the ellipses. Try adding `transform-origin: center center;` and `transform-box: fill-box;` as mentioned above